# Como configurar mi aplicación para arrancar con Windows

Tags: c#, wpf

quisiera saber como puedo hacer para que mi aplicación arranque junto con Windows, en si cuando el usuario inicie sesión. Llevo unos días y lo único que veo en Google es sobre como crear accesos directos en Inicio de la carpeta Windows, que no me parece lo mejor. ¿Sera que es la única forma?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay otra alternativa para que su programa/archivo, se ejecute en el inicio de Windows. Usando las funciones que permiten crear claves de registro e implementar valores en estas mismas, puede consultar sus claves de registro si presiona **Windows + R** y en la entrada que le pide digitar 'regedit', lo llevará a el editor de registro, el cual básicamente es como una base de datos interna de su sistema operativo, puede leer mas sobre esto en: [Registro de Windows](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registro_de_Windows).

A continuación le mostraré una de las maneras en que puede implementar la solución de su problema con **C#**:

Necesita aplicar:

```
using System.Linq;        // Para usar la función 'Contains()'
using Microsoft.Win32;    // Para poder acceder a las claves de registro
```

Luego abrir la clave de registro necesaria y establecerla en una variable, en este caso, se llamará 'key':

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
```

La ruta que visualiza es la que predeterminadamente contiene los valores establecidos por las aplicaciones que inician automáticamente (Efectivamente, luego de **'Equipo\HKEY_CURRENT_USER'**, que será el apartado en donde crearemos el valor de su programa (Usuario actual de su maquina), no hace falta poner esa parte de la ruta, por lo que ya **'Registry.CurrentUser'** en su código, accede a él).

Después, algo *'opcional'*, es revisar si ya el valor se estableció, esto para que el programa no sobrescriba el valor en la clave de registro innecesariamente cada vez que se inicie el programa:

```
if(key.GetValueNames().Contains("Prueba") == false)
```

No creo que haga falta explicar mucho esta parte, solo aclarar que se está obteniendo el nombre de los valores guardados en la clave establecida con nuestra variable 'key', y con el **Contains** busca si hay un valor llamado 'Prueba', o el que usted le ponga en el código.

Si no encuentra ningún valor con ese nombre, se ejecutará la función que crea un nuevo valor:

```
key.SetValue("Prueba", "C:\\MiPrograma.exe");
```

**Primer parametro:**
Se le dará el nombre del que hablamos anteriormente, puede ser cualquiera de su preferencia, pero recuerde que de debe ser el mismo en el que se comprueba con el **IF**, eso significa que tendría que cambiarle el nombre en ambas partes.

**Segundo parametro:**
Ruta del archivo/programa que quiere adherir a los valores de registro que inician con Windows.

Finalmente solo falta cerrar la clave que abrimos con nuestra variable, esto para que no se generen inconvenientes a la hora de que se cierre el programa inesperadamente, etc:

```
key.Close();
```

Código completo:

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace MiProyecto
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Abrir clave de registro
            RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
            
            // Comprobar si ya existe el valor (Su ejecutable/archivo)
            if(key.GetValueNames().Contains("Prueba") == false)      // Nombre del valor en la clave de registro
            {
                key.SetValue("Prueba", "C:\\MiPrograma.exe");        // Parametro 1: Nombre del valor, Parametro 2: Ruta del archivo
            }

            // Cerrar clave de registro (Recomendable para prevenir inconvenientes)
            key.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**Recomendaciones:**
Su valor en la clave de registro mencionada tendrá la ruta que implemente en el código, si su ejecutable se mueve a otra ruta, provocará que su programa no inicie correctamente, por lo que ya el valor de registro tiene una ruta predeterminada, para prevenir esto, asegúrese de que su cliente o el usuario que vaya a utilizar la aplicación tenga el mismo ejecutable en un directorio seguro, y para usar este mismo, ser ejecutado mediante accesos directos (Una de las razones y formas que usan los instaladores al poner la aplicación principal en el disco **C:\** y evitar problemas con las rutas establecidas en el registro).

Recuerde otorgar permisos de administrador al programa para evitar molestias. Puede leer mas sobre la manipulación de registros en: [Key registry C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-create-a-key-in-the-registry).

Comment: Meterle mano al registro suena un poco overkill cuando existe la posibilidad de definir un servicio del sistema al que se le puede configurar el Autostart.

Answer (score 0):

No sé si te servirá, con el programador de Tareas de Windows en la pestaña desencadenador hay una opción de Iniciar sesión.